# Firebase Analytics - firebase-core:9.0.0 - FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: INVALID_SENDER

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase

I followed the instructions on the following page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

The initialization process works fine but I see the error message like mentioned in the title.

Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After re downloading the google-services.json the message disappeared...
Now I get "FirebaseInstanceId: topic sync succeeded".

Thank you anyway. Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely ignore this working. Its overactive logging when the device is offline or fails to reach the server.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened when the emulator I was debugging on had no internet connection. This can happen if you change the internet settings within the emulator - it seems like the emulator may require a restart to make the internet connection work again even if you re-enable it in the emulator settings.

To get rid of the error - change the emulator settings to enable the internet then restart the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you project_number in your google-services.json matches the one in your Firebase Console.